# How to convert time structure to ISO 8601 format of yyyy-mm-dd in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, structure

I have a time structure that looks like this:

```
 time.year=str2num(fileNames(i).name(29:32));
 time.month=str2num(fileNames(i).name(33:34));
 time.day=str2num(fileNames(i).name(35:36));
 time.hour=str2num(fileNames(i).name(37:38));
 time.min=str2num(fileNames(i).name(39:40));
 time.sec=30;
 time.UTC=-7;
```

and I need to get from this ISO 8601 format of yyyy-mm-dd, any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: If you wanted to go right to Matlab `datenum` values from those filenames and shorten your parsing code, you could do something like `t = datenum([filenames(i).name(29:40) '30'], 'yyyymmddHHMMSS');`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) function:

```
timeVec = [time.year time.month time.day time.hour time.min time.sec];
timeStr = datestr(timeVec,'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Will give you the local date/time.

```
timeVec = [time.year time.month time.day time.hour-time.UTC time.min time.sec];
timeStr = datestr(timeVec,'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Should provide Zulu date/time if your hours roll over to the next day.

To add the time string to your output, just change the format string to `'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS'`.

Another good resource is the Mathwork's [documentaion on representing dates and times in MATLAB.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/represent-date-and-times-in-MATLAB.html)